# Запуск таймера, остановка, снова запуск: либо не запускается, либо не останавливается

Tags: javascript, jquery, таймер

Порядок действий таков: есть модальное окно (fancybox3), пользователь открывает окно и выполняет в нем какое-то действие (жмет кнопку и получает ответ от сервера). При получении ответа запускается таймер. По истечении таймера происходят всякие мелкие команды типа скрыть элемент, показать другой элемент и т.п.

Если таймер истек сам и потом триггер его снова запускает (клик/ответ от сервера - не имеет значения), то всё нормально.

Проблемы с которыми столкнулся и не смог решить:

1. Триггер может быть нажат сколько угодно раз пока таймер работает. Он не должен перезапускаться и накладываться друг на друга. Как сделать проверку: если таймер работает - не запускать повторно?
   Пробовал так: `if(typeof timerId == 'undefined' || !timerId) initializeTimer();` , но работает только в первый раз.
2. Если модальное окно закрывается (я отлавливаю этот момент функционалом fancy), то надо останавливать таймер. 
   Если таймер не запускался, а окно закрыть, в консоли появляется ошибка. Чтобы избавиться, я сделал проверку `if(typeof timerId != 'undefined') clearInterval(timerId);` . Но если после этого открыть окно и вызвать триггер, то таймер уже не стартует.
3. В модальном окне две вкладки (активная и скрытая, они могут меняться). Таймер на странице только 1 будет работать, но может запускаться и там и там (не одновременно). Верстка примерно идентичная (таймер внутри формы). Как можно изменить функцию вывода, чтобы появилась возможность задавать место вывода? Или задавать жестко место вывода параметром (имеются как общие там и уникальные классы и id у форм и оберток) или определять какое окно/форма сейчас видна и там запускать.

Таймер нашел на просторах инета, поковырялся, удалил лишнее (дни, часы оставил из-за формулы подсчета минут).

```
function initializeTimer(local) {
    var seconds = 180000 / 1000; // определяем количество секунд до истечения таймера
    if (seconds > 0) { 
        var minutes = seconds/60; // определяем количество минут до истечения таймера
        //var hours = minutes/60; // определяем количество часов до истечения таймера
        //minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60; // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
        //hours = Math.floor(hours); // целое количество часов до истечения таймера
        seconds = Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60); // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся секунд в текущей минуте
        minutes = Math.floor(minutes); // округляем до целого кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе

        setTimePage(minutes,seconds,local); // выставляем начальные значения таймера

        function secOut() {
          if (seconds < 2) { // если секунду закончились то (после завершения ещё 1 сек задержки, поэтому ставим 2, чтобы увидеть 1 и завершить)
              if (minutes == 0) { // если минуты закончились то
                  showMessage(timerId); // выводим сообщение об окончании отсчета
                  return;
              }else{
                  minutes--; // уменьшаем кол-во минут
                  seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
              }
          }else{
              seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд
          }
          setTimePage(minutes,seconds); // обновляем значения таймера на странице
        }
        timerId = setInterval(secOut, 1000) // устанавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
    }else{
        console.log("Ошибка таймера");
    }
}

function setTimePage(m,s,local) { // функция выставления таймера на странице
    auth_form.find('#timer_wrap').html('<div id="timer">'+m+' мин. '+s+' сек.</div>');
    // тут еще задания типа скрыть кнопку, показать другую, очистить поле
}

function showMessage(timerId) { // функция, вызываемая по истчению времени
    clearInterval(timerId); // останавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
    auth_form.find('#'+local+'').html('<div id="timer">Время закончилось</div>');
    // тут еще задания типа скрыть кнопку, показать другую, очистить поле
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главная Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы полагаете что `clearInterval()` очистит переменную `timerId`.

На самом же деле эта функция примет аргумент вычистит интервал из памяти но не обнулит переменную `timerId`

1. Таким образом ваша проверка не даст ничего, ведь в переменной `timerId` так и останется id уже удаленного интервала. В таком случае нужно **явно** обнулять `timerId` после очистки интервала:

   `clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = undefined;`
2. Я полагаю ответ идентичен, данный кусок кода для ответа бесполезен, вам стоит привести пример именно того кода в котором и возникает проблема.
3. Правильнее всего, на мой взгляд будет работать внутри самого таймера исключительно с секундами, а функцию `setTimePage` переписать так, что бы в ней секунды преобразовывались в необходимое время. Что касается, самого вопроса, можно например передавать параметром в эту же функцию блок в котором необходимо отрисовывать таймер.

## UPD. Реализация таймера в секундах.

```js
function timer() {
  // блоки в которых необходимо выводить таймер
  var block1 = document.getElementById("block1");
  var block2 = document.getElementById("block2");

  // количество секунд можете считать как вам угодно
  var seconds = 82000;

  // основной таймер
  var timer_id = setInterval(function() {
    if (seconds < 1) {
      clearInterval(timer_id);
      timer_id = undefined;
    }

    //выводит в разные блоки в зависимости от условия
    if (seconds % 2) output(block1, seconds);
    else output(block2, seconds);

    seconds--;
  }, 1000)
}

function output(block, seconds) {
  var hours, minutes, h, m, s;
  seconds = Math.min(seconds, 60 * 60 * 24); // ограничение на 24 часа

  // делим секунды на количество секунд в часе
  hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  // остаток от предыдущего деления делим на количество минут
  minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
  // все оставшиеся секунды
  seconds = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) % 60);

  // если число не двузначное добавляем 0 впереди, числа станут строками, по этому создаем новые переменные что бы не потерять возможности арифметических операций
  h = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours.toString();
  m = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes.toString();
  s = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds.toString();

  // если секунды равны 0 (нет смысла в более точных проверках, она уже сделана выше), то выводим сообщение об оуончании таймера
  if (!seconds) {
    block.innerHTML = "<span class='time'>" + "Fin." + "</span>";
  } else {
    block.innerHTML = "<span class='time'>" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "</span>";
  }
}

timer();
```

```css
.timer {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.timer+.timer {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer" id="block1"></div>
<div class="timer" id="block2"></div>
```

Comment: `timerId = undefined` - единственный вариант определить работает таймер или нет? Добавил эту очистку в функцию закрытия модального окна и в функцию `showMessage` после `clearInterval` . В итоге, пункт №2 решен. Но выявилась другая проблема - если таймер завершился самостоятельно, но изначальный триггер не может его запустить через `if(typeof timerId == 'undefined') initializeTimer();` . Надо закрыть окно, открыть и только после этого получится стартовать таймер. Где ошибка и как исправить? По поводу setTimePage и места отрисовки - буду признателен коду, моих навыков не хватает.

Comment: Вы же в коде можете проверить что таймер окончен, просто там же а конкретно здесь `console.log("Ошибка таймера");` замените на `timerId = undefined;`

Comment: как? Касательно замены `console.log` - зачем там указывать `undefined`? Это же условие на случай, если тут `var seconds = 10000 / 1000` значение поставим неверное и получим число меньше нуля.

Comment: Оу действительно прошу прощения, на глаз ошибся веткой. В функции `secOut` нужно сделать проверку если оставшееся количество секунд равно 0, еще раз повторюсь, рекомендую перевести все только в секунды, по тому что иначе придется вводить проверку и на то что количество минут равно 0, в этой проверке просто выставляете `timerId = undefined;`

Comment: Да, действительно, добавил `timerId = undefined;` в функции `secOut` после `showMessage(timerId);` . Таймер стал перезапускаться. Только почему так, если `timerId = undefined;` у меня в функции `showMessage(timerId);` уже имеется? Так там и сейчас там, сначала проверка секунд потом минут. Как переписать на чистые сек? И по поводу места вывода тоже очень нужен совет в виде строчек кода, мыль с передачей параметра я понял, но реализовать не могу.

Comment: Вот что касается вывода: https://jsfiddle.net/4yhgwefv/5/

Comment: По поводу таймера, все очень просто, вы считаете время в секундах  например 180  (это 3 минуты) и каждую секунду отнимаете еденицу. передаете секунды в вашу функцию вывода и там преобразуете секунды в часы минуты и секунды.

Comment: В вашем примере вы объявляете глобальную переменную - а это не очень хорошо. Я сделал несколько иначе, но всё равно спасибо за пример. По поводу `timerId = undefined;` в вопросе выше так и осталось загадкой для меня. По поводу таймера - только на слова просто)

Comment: Я всего лишь продемонстрировал гипотетическую работу функции, глобальные переменные подразумевают что Вы будете использовать их внутри какой то функции, не стоит относиться так серьезно к примеру написанному за пару минут.

Comment: Дополнил код полным рабочим примером с реализацией таймера в секундах.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пример. Есть моменты, требующие уточнения: 1. Почему таймер запускается сразу в двух блоках? Я пытался передать параметр block1/block2 в функцию запуска, но не вышло. Эти два блока всегда будут одновременно присутствовать на странице, именно в вызове надо определять, где показать. 2. А как принудительно остановить и обнулить таймер до его истечения (и возможно было повторно запустить) ? 3. Почему присутствует примерно секундная задержка до запуска? 4. Почему почему не в миллисекундах? Ну и вкусовщина: часы и нули не нужны, хотя это я и сам могу убрать.

Comment: 1. Два блока лишь в качестве примера, вы можете создать два и более экземпляра таймера и выводить их куда угодно. функция `output` всегда принимает блок внутри которого будет создан таймер это лишь на ваше усмотрение. Удобнее всего сразу создать все необходимы блоки на странице и скрывать их через `display: none` вместо того что бы каждый раз создавать новый.
2. Подобный функционал можно дописать, у вас есть текущее время в секундах если вы прервете интервал раньше времени вы всегда можете его продолжить. Либо же полностью удалить объект и создать новый.

Comment: 3. Это из-за `setInterval`, не обратил на это внимания. В таком случае следует вынести анонимную функцию, дать ей имя и выполнять сразу а затем в интервале каждую секунду.
_Почему почему не в миллисекундах?_
Вам нужна такая точность? Обновление интервала каждую миллисекунду абсолютно ненужная нагрузка на процессор. 
_Ну и вкусовщина: часы и нули не нужны, хотя это я и сам могу убрать._ Я лишь привел пример, а не выполнил ваше задание за вас.

Comment: Я сделал набросок таймера с использованием "классов", можете посмотреть: jsfiddle.net/6odkfc04/32
Нажмите кнопку P (английскую) несколько раз что бы увидеть как таймер ставится на паузу.